# Imprimir parágrafo en forma horizontal no en vertical en C#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

tengo la siguiente instrucción con la que logro escribir en un documento pdf, el contenido que añada dentro de las comillas

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         doc.Add(new Paragraph("-"));
     }
```

en este caso me imprime

```
-
-
-
-
-
```

lo que requiero hacer es que me imprima de esta forma

```
-----
```

que instruccion puedo añadir

Comment: Lo que indica Leandro en su respuesta es correcto. Esto se debe a que un párrafo es una secuencia de texto que termina con un fin de línea. Cada párrafo debe iniciar en una línea nueva. Es lo que provoca el efecto que tienes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberias ir uniendo en una variable para luego agregarla al documento

```
string temp = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    temp = temp + "-";
}

doc.Add(new Paragraph(temp));
```

Tambien hay otra forma usando el `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    sb.Append("-");
}

doc.Add(new Paragraph(sb.ToString()));
```

para unir texto entiendo es mas performante, aunque en este caso al ser un loop pequeño no se notara la diferencia